# Changing the numbers' font in LaTeX is not working

Tags: math-mode, fonts

I used a code I found here for changing the numbers' font in LaTeX but it doesn't work :(
the name of my font is "MiLetra". I've already tried putting "MiLetra.ttf" and "MiLetra.otf" (using ttf and otf versions of it) but it doesn't change anything.

This is what I put:

```
\documentclass{article}
  \DeclareSymbolFont{numbers}{T1}{MiLetra}{m}{n}
  \SetSymbolFont{numbers}{bold}{T1}{MiLetra}{bx}{n}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{0}\mathalpha{numbers}{"30}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{1}\mathalpha{numbers}{"31}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{2}\mathalpha{numbers}{"32}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{3}\mathalpha{numbers}{"33}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{4}\mathalpha{numbers}{"34}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{5}\mathalpha{numbers}{"35}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{6}\mathalpha{numbers}{"36}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{7}\mathalpha{numbers}{"37}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{8}\mathalpha{numbers}{"38}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{9}\mathalpha{numbers}{"39}

\begin{document}
abc

$a=123$

\mathversion{bold}

$a=345$
\end{document}
```

If anyone knows what could be happening I would really appreciate a little help.
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Did you compile with xelatex or with pdflatex?

Comment: Thanks! I tried with both, none of them works :(

Comment: did you setup a `t1miletra.fd` file with the font declarations?

Comment: if asking for help with an error it helps if you show the exact error message. pdflatex can not directly use otf or ttf fonts you must use external tools to make tfm font metric files. xelatex and lualatex can access the fonts but you would normally use `fontspec` but you are using classic fd file access via `{T1}{MiLetra}{m}{n}`

Comment: You xelatex, you have to use the real name of the font (which you may find with a font manager. such as Nexus Font). With pdflatex, you have th make the `tfm` and `vf` files (details on the site of `lcdf type tools`.

Answer (score 1):

With XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

\newfontfamily{\miletra}{MILETRA}[
  NFSSFamily=MiLetra,
  Path=./,
  Extension=.ttf,
  UprightFont=*,
  BoldFont=*,
  BoldFeatures={FakeBold=3},
]

\DeclareSymbolFont{numbers}{TU}{MiLetra}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{numbers}{bold}{TU}{MiLetra}{bx}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{0}\mathalpha{numbers}{"30}
\DeclareMathSymbol{1}\mathalpha{numbers}{"31}
\DeclareMathSymbol{2}\mathalpha{numbers}{"32}
\DeclareMathSymbol{3}\mathalpha{numbers}{"33}
\DeclareMathSymbol{4}\mathalpha{numbers}{"34}
\DeclareMathSymbol{5}\mathalpha{numbers}{"35}
\DeclareMathSymbol{6}\mathalpha{numbers}{"36}
\DeclareMathSymbol{7}\mathalpha{numbers}{"37}
\DeclareMathSymbol{8}\mathalpha{numbers}{"38}
\DeclareMathSymbol{9}\mathalpha{numbers}{"39}

\begin{document}

abc $a=123$

\mathversion{bold}

$a=345$

\end{document}
```

Your font setup might need to be slightly different. This is for `MILETRA.ttf` in the same directory as the main file (with faked bold because there isn't a bold version in the version I found).

[image]